# Min and Max in one Group by query

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

The following query does not run if I include the MAX(col1) in the select clause

```
SELECT AVG(col1),
       MIN(col1),
       --ΜΑΧ(col1),      
       COUNT(*),
       col2
FROM   view
GROUP BY col2;
```

how can I rewrite this to get MAX(col1)? using subqueries?

Comment: Max(col1) is not working in same query . is it?

Comment: How does it not run?  Is there an error?

Comment: What output do you actually want?

Comment: Correct, if I uncomment the commented line it throws an error. Oracle tells me this: ORA-00904: "ΜΑΧ": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 7

Comment: As an output I want for all col2 groups to know the col1 avg, max and median.

Comment: It should work. Check MAX symbols for national codepage ones.

Comment: It is the same thing if I use MAX instead of MIN and have MIN included in the select clause as the third column, the query does not run

Comment: To be more precise, the data come from a view, not a table. Is this of any significance?

Comment: try running same query but comment out all other function except max.

Comment: I just opened a second tab on oracle sql developer, typed the query adding the columns of the select clause one by one and running it each time. in the end it worked......absolutely nonsense this is! So  I have 2 tabs now with the same exact query, on the left one it does not run, on the right one it does.

Comment: Restart your client (SQL developer) and check again ?

Comment: Just restarted, now it runs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having unicode trouble:

```
ΜΑΧ(col1) -- will not execute
MAX(col1) -- will execute
```

The first one consists of GREEK CAPITAL LETTERs,

Μ is a GREEK CAPITAL LETTER MU (see [this](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%CE%9C&mode=char)) etc.